# Why doesn't .attr("src", "/some/path/image.png") work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to replace the src of an  tag with another path. This works perfectly well:

```
var tempDocId = 'someId';
$('#documents' + that.ticketId).append('<img id="'+tempDocId+'" src="/img/support/pdf_icon.jpg">');
```

but the following code gives one of those "image not found" icons ([image]):

```
var tempDocId = 'someId';
$('#documents' + that.ticketId).append('<img id="'+tempDocId+'" src="/img/support/loading.jpg">');
$('#tempDocId').attr("src", "/img/support/pdf_icon.jpg");
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Might be because the `<img>` gets its ID dynamically. Shouldnt this `$('#tempDocId')` be `$('#'+tempDocId+')`

Comment: Don't create elements in crappy way. If you want to create an element just do it like  `var img = document.createElement('img'); $(img).attr(...); $("#tempDocId").append(img);`

Comment: **Here is what I can't understand:** if `$('#tempDocId')` does not match any element why would it result in an `image not found icon`. Something else is going on! Don't you think so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you are looking for id="tempDocId", not the one you generated.

```
$('#tempDocId').attr("src", "/img/support/pdf_icon.jpg");
```

needs to be

```
$('#' + tempDocId).attr("src", "/img/support/pdf_icon.jpg");
```

so you are not replacing the source. My guess is that your loading image is not valid.

Comment: This doesn't explain the problem. The loading image "works perfectly well", but the second code replaces it with a broken image. Explain!

Answer (score 0):

Because `$('#tempDocId')` doesn't exist. `tempDocId` is a variable, so try:

```
$('#' + tempDocId).attr('src', '/img/support/pdf_icon.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tempDocId = 'doc' + Math.random().toString().substr(2);
var $img = $('<img id="'+tempDocId+'" src="/img/support/loading.jpg">');
$img.appendTo('#documents' + that.ticketId);
$img.attr('src', '/img/support/pdf_icon.jpg');
```